# Python - How to make the program go back to the first while loop, in the second while loop

Tags: python, loops

Im trying to go back to the start of the first while loop in the second while loop.

```
loop_again = True # I want it to come back here
while loop_again:
    swap = "no" #LOOP 1
    while swap:
        import random #imports the random number function
        D1 = random.randrange(1,7)#sets random number from 1 to 6
        D2 = random.randrange(1,7)
        print (input("Press ENTER to roll the dice"))
        print (D1, D2)


        if D1 == 1 or D2 == 1:#checks if either dice is a 1
            total = (D1 + D2)
            P1_S = (P1_S - total)
            con = (input("Press ENTER to continue"))
            print ("Score: " +P1, P1_S)
        elif D1 and D2 == 1:
            P1_S = (P1_S + 25)
            con = (input("Press ENTER to continue"))
            print ("Score: " +P1, P1_S)
        elif D1 == D2:
            total = (D1 + D2)*2
            P1_S = (P1_S + total)
            con = (input("Press ENTER to continue"))
            print ("Score: " +P1, P1_S)
        else:
            total = (D1 + D2)
            P1_S = (P1_S + total)
            con = (input("Press ENTER to continue"))
            print ("Score: " +P1, P1_S)

        if D1 == 1 or D2 == 1:
            print ("Pass dice to " +P2,".")
            break
        else:
            swap = (input("Do you want to pass to the next player?"))
            if swap == "yes":
                print ("It is now "+P2,"'s turn")
                break
            elif swap == "no":
                print ("Press ENTER to continue")

swap = "no" #LOOP 2
while swap:
    import random #imports the random number function
    D1 = random.randrange(1,7)#sets random number from 1 to 6
    D2 = random.randrange(1,7)
    print (input("Press ENTER to roll the dice"))
    print (D1, D2)


    if D1 == 1 or D2 == 1:
        total = (D1 + D2)
        P2_S = (P2_S - total)
        con = (input("Press ENTER to continue"))
        print ("Score: " +P2, P2_S)
    elif D1 and D2 == 1:
        P2_S = (P2_S + 25)
        con = (input("Press ENTER to continue"))
        print ("Score: " +P2, P2_S)
    elif D1 == D2:
        total = (D1 + D2)*2
        P2_S = (P2_S + total)
        con = (input("Press ENTER to continue"))
        print ("Score: " +P2, P2_S)
    else:
        total = (D1 + D2)
        P2_S = (P2_S + total)
        con = (input("Press ENTER to continue"))
        print ("Score: " +P2, P2_S)

    if D1 == 1 or D2 == 1:
        if num_ps == "3" or num_ps == "4":
            print ("Pass dice to " +P3,".")
        elif num_ps != "3" or num_ps != "4":
            print ("It is now "+P1,"'s turn")# I want to go back from HERE

    else:
        swap = (input("Do you want to pass to the next player?"))
        if swap == "yes":
            if num_ps == "3" or num_ps == "4":
                print ("It is now "+P3,"'s turn")
                break
            elif num_ps != "3" or num_ps != "4":
                print("It is now "+P1,"'s turn") # and HERE
        elif swap == "no":
            print ("Press ENTER to continue")
```

The thing is I have tried using continue, return and count and they haven.t worked. Is there a way to do this at all?

Comment: Put them both in another `while loop_again` loop?

Comment: Just put the first loop in a function, then call that function at the end of second loop.

Comment: Instead of going back, why don't just reset the value of all variables?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara I attempted to use another while loop,but it didnt work. Is there a way to put 2 different loops inside one loop?

Comment: @KoraliteOtaku: Indent the second one too.